# How to change color of git changes in JetBrains IDE (PhpStorm)

Tags: themes, jetbrains-ide, uicolor

I want to change the color of git changes in my IDE. For my personal comfort I want to change the "deleted files" color to red.

[image: IDE image with what I want to change]

I've tried changing the color in the IDE settings but I could not find the right place. Maybe I need to make changes in the theme settings?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings` -> `Version Control` -> `File Status Colors`

And change the value of `Deleted` by the color of your choice (red for you)

[image: Settings path to change the color]

The new color:

[image: Exemple File Deleted]